# Comparison of LINQ to SPARQL?

Tags: linq, sparql

I'm not a MS.NET person but got curious about LINQ, and this article http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx explains very well why it's better than SQL.

I work a lot with SPARQL and in many respects it's worse than SQL (even 1.1 is a bit immature IMHO). Is there a comparison of LINQ to SPARQL in the style of the above article?

I think the LINQ aspect that's most interesting for RDF data is that LINQ can return hierarchical structures (in RDBMS speak that's table-valued variables; or think XML structures). SPARQL cannot do that:

- you can't make CONSTRUCT subqueries, see [GroupGraphPattern](http://vladimiralexiev.github.io/SPARQL/sparql11-grammar.xhtml#GroupGraphPattern)
  and [SubSelect](http://vladimiralexiev.github.io/SPARQL/sparql11-grammar.xhtml#SubSelect) in the grammar
- if you try to return an array of complexly CONSTRUCTed objects, I bet you'll get a mess. Nor I believe you can mix arrays & hierarchical structures several levels deep. If you disagree, see this http://vocab.getty.edu/doc/queries/#All_Data_For_Subject and try to write a query to return it for all `?s gvp:broaderExtended aat:300264089` (disclaimers: I built that endpoint)

So with SPARQL we either return tabular data, or a single graph object but can't mix them freely. Which is ironic, because RDF **is** a graph data model.

There are several LINQ to SPARQL bindings:

- https://github.com/Efimster/LINQtoSPARQL
- http://rdfsharp.codeplex.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/linqtordf/
- http://www.dotnetrdf.org/
- http://brightstardb.com
- https://github.com/semiodesk/trinity-rdf

But does any of them handle this "hierarchical structures" aspect?

Comment: I think this question is probably too broad at the moment to be a good fit for Stack Overflow, but I'm trying to understand some of your use cases.  You can represent hierarchical data in RDF, so you can certainly construct it as well.  Can you explain your example in a bit more, perhaps simpler, though, detail?

Comment: "so you can certainly CONSTRUCT it" (in sparql) is not substantiated.

Comment: My prev comment is too harsh, so let me elaborate it. In my experience it's very hard in SPARQL to intermix tabular and graph results, and to return complex entities (subgraphs) if the selection of (finding) these entities is also complex. Also see SPARQL 1.2 issue https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/100

Answer (score 0):

(I prefer this to be a comment but it is too too long)

I am not an expert, neither in LINQ nor SPARQL, and I didn't check the links you've provided, but recently I've listened to a Podcast with Anders Heilsberg, Microsoft Technical Fellow, and Lead Designer of C# and LINQ.

http://www.se-radio.net/2008/05/episode-97-interview-anders-hejlsberg/

He said that LINQ syntax follows a FROM ... WHERE ... SELECT structure to allow for better type inference.

When it knows the table name (FROM ... clause) the type inference engine in LINQ can start working at compile time, to fetch the column names for the autocompleter, and e.g interact with the syntax checker in Visual Studio.

I don't think this is easy/possible for a RDF triple where the property/predicate (SELECT /WHERE)  can even be empty, but not FROM, (Blank Nodes).

These Blank Nodes denote existence of an individual with specific attributes, but without providing an identification or reference).